# Can I upload apks for multiple architectures into the Google Play store without using the android NDK?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, cpu-architecture, crosswalk-runtime

I need to produce 2 apks, one for x86 and one for ARM. I do this with different versions of crosswalk, which internally uses cordova. All I need to do one the two projects are created is `./cordova/build --release` and then sign the APK. The Google Play store docs mention a way of uploading both into a single app listing, but they assume I'm using the Android NDK, which I'm not. Will I need to start using it or is there another way to simply upload both apks?

Comment: Do you use native code? I means, do you have any file .so?

Comment: No, I'm currently using 2 versions of cordova-compatible crosswalk to make the builds: One which is produces x86-compatible apps, the other which produces ARM-compatible apps. So I now have two separate apks, and although crosswalk may use native code, I dont do so myself...

Answer (score 2):

Google does support posting of architechture-specific APKs: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html.  Note however that the documentation states, in **bold**:

> we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK

So, if you take the single APK approach:

Just compile your native code into libraries (i.e. .so files) and place them in the following locations

```xml
<Project_Root>/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/
```

and

```xml
<Project_Root>/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86/
```

The build process will package these in the appropriate manner so that your APK contains libs for both architectures.  Then at runtime, Android will ensure that the architecture-appropriate library is loaded.

Note that the above assumes that you are using Gradle to build your APKs.  If you are using the old ant-based build process, the locations are slightly different:

```xml
<Project_Root>/libs/armeabi/
```

and

```xml
<Project_Root>/libs/x86/
```

Comment: I don't know how to produce `.so` files. You say the build process will build an APK containing the libs for both architectures.. What build process is that? `cordova build --release`? By the way: I would prefer not having a single APK, which would become huge, but rather having 2 APKs, one for each architecture. That is what is recommended online..

Comment: I did not realize this is a Cordova app, although that does not matter.  I believe Cordova uses the standard Android build tools to produce an APK.  That is what I mean by the "build process".

Comment: That is interesting.  When you say the APK would become "huge" does that mean that you have a very large amount of native code?  I have never seen a recommendation that multiple architecture-specific versions of the same app be posted.  Do you have a pointer to this?  It seems it would be a release management headache to support this.  Plus it might confuse users who go to the app store.

Comment: I just found a Google link that sheds some light on this.   I will include it in the answer...

Comment: I'd be willing to give it a try, but I still don't understand what I'm supposed to do. How do I create `.so` files? Once I've placed the separated `.so` files in the specified folders, how do I turn them into a single APK?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear.  It is not APKs that you put in those folders.  It is the arch-specific .so library files you put there.

Comment: As for how to build the SO files, here is a link to try: http://android-jotting.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-build-sharedstatic-library-so.html. However, it is hard to give specific instructions as I have no information about your project and build process.  If you are already compiling native (C/C++) code, then it's possible your build is already producing these.  But again, I just dont have enough info about how your project is setup.

Comment: My build process is just calling `./cordova/build --release` form within the crosswalk project. I do this twice, one for the x86 project, the other for the ARM project...

Comment: Here is the link advising the 2 apk approach: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#How-can-I-distribute-a-Crosswalk-Android-application-across-multiple-architectures

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with Crosswalk or Cordova builds.  My suggestion to you would be to post this as a new question.  Now that you have an approach, something ask something like "How do I get my Cordova/Crosswalk build to generate a single APK for all archs?"  Be sure also to include more info about your native code and how that is currently integrated with your project.

Comment: Actually the link you provided has the answer.  Just search for "Build one package for your application"  The next couple of paragraphs spell out the process.

Comment: Reading through this, I see I now have clarity on where the native code comes from.  It is CrossWalk itself that provides the SO files.